# The size parameter from function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, widestring, widechar

I see that a lot of functions need you to set a size for the string which is the output.

**GetComputerNameW** needs:

```
WCHAR wStrName[16U];
DWORD uSize = 16U;
GetComputerNameW(wStrName, &uSize);
```

**RegSetValueExW** needs:

```
WCHAR wStrExec[1024U];
RegSetValueExW(..., (wcslen(wStrExec) + 1U) * sizeof(WCHAR));
```

**GetWindowTextW** needs:

```
WCHAR wStrText[1024U];
GetWindowsTextW(..., sizeof(wStrText));
```

**GetModuleBaseNameW** needs:

```
WCHAR wStrName[1024U];
GetModuleBaseNameW(..., sizeof(wStrName) / sizeof(WCHAR));
```

My question is, how to make the difference between the sizes set? The strings are always defined as WCHAR and the sizes set differ so much.

Comment: In short, you need to read the documentation of each individual function, determine exactly what needs to be passed, then pass that.  Note that `sizeof(wStrName) / sizeof(WCHAR)` can be shortened to `_countof(wStrName)`, using `_countof` from the Visual C++ `<stdlib.h>` (`_countof` is a nonstandard extension).

Comment: Could you rephrase your question please? I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking why we need to pass size information, or how these functions make use of the size information, or something else?

Comment: Your `GetWindowTextW` is incorrect. It should be 1024 or `sizeof(wStrText) / sizeof(WCHAR)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll see that the size parameter is the size of the output buffer in bytes typically:

```
cbData [in]
```

> The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, in
>   bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ,
>   cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or
>   characters.

Which of course yields that you need to:

```
WCHAR wStrExec[1024U];
RegSetValueExW(..., sizeof (wStrExec));
```

Comment: In the case of `RegSetValueExW` with a string, you should only use the part of the buffer that contains data. Otherwise you're writing uninitialized stack garbage into the registry which could be an information disclosure security vulnerability.

Comment: @RaymondChen:  Fair enough.